# How to load file in binary format

Tags: c#, windows, oop, for-loop

I have used this code and try to load text file. But it's got an error. The error showing in "loaddate()" I have passed returen value also// here I try to do created an list and upload data into list.

```
public partial class RegisterUser : Form
{
    List<Log> list = null;

    public RegisterUser()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
      //  list = new List<Log>();
        list = loadData();
    }

    public List<Log> loadData() 
    {
        List<Log> lst = null;
        if (File.Exists("Login.bin"))
        {
            Stream stream = File.Open("Login.bin", FileMode.Open);
            BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            lst = (List<Log>)bformatter.Deserialize(stream);
            stream.Close();

        }
        else
        {
            lst = new List<Log>();
        }
        return lst;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which error do you get? Is the file locked by another process?

Comment: Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<XYZ_System.Log>' is less accessible than method 'XYZ_System.RegisterUser.loadData()' E:\Degree Assignment\Application development-semester 1\XYZ_System\XYZ_System\RegisterUser.cs 27 26 XYZ_System

Comment: make your Log class public

Comment: thank you.. itz working... Amazing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want a little explanation for your problem:

You have an public class `RegisterUser`.
In this public class you have a public function `loadData`.
So the return value is visible in all other classes.

But you return a type, which is not visible from all other classes.

That's bad. You could call the function but you cannot see the return type.
Thats why the `Log` class has also to be public.

if your class `RegisterUser` would be `private` or `internal`, than the `Log` class could have the same access type.

Hope this helps you for the next time.